# Finding total sum of the sum of different columns of different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say we have 3 tables A, B and C with same columns `district`, `population`.
I need to find the sum of all the `population`s from all the tables in a single query.
I am not too proficient with queries and haven't made the structure yet but would like to know if a query like below will work or not.

```
select Sum(SUM1+SUM2+SUM3) 
from tableA A, tableB B, tableC C 
where SUM1 = sum(A.population) 
  and SUM2 = sum(B.population) 
  and SUM3 = sum(C.population) ;
```

Any other suggestions are also welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `union all`:

```
select sum(t.population)
from (
   select population from table A
   union all
   select population from table B
   union all
   select population from table A
) t
```

Comment: Thanks a lot potashin :).

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
SELECT COALESCE((SELECT SUM(population) FROM TableA),0) + 
       COALESCE((SELECT SUM(population) FROM TableB),0) +
       COALESCE((SELECT SUM(population) FROM TableC),0) AS TotalPopulation
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf0ef/1)

Comment: one of the `sum`s _may_ return `null`, thus causing cumulative sum become also `null`, for a general-case solution you can use `coalesce` to prevent this behaviour.

Comment: @potashin Good catch! I've edited my answer, thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks a lot Giorgos :).